# Проблема получения HttpStatus 400

Tags: java, json, spring, http, rest

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать регистрацию через spring security.

Вот метод контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> registration(@RequestBody User newUser, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        User user = userService.save(newUser);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
    }
```

Сервис:

```
  @Override
    public User save(User user) {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
            roles.add(roleRepository.getOne(1L));
            user.setRoles(roles);
            User newUser = userRepository.save(user);
            return newUser;
    }
```

Запрос делаю в json. Когда Есть username и password, то получаю 201

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нету или username, или password, то приходит 500

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо 500 приходила 400-ошибка? Потому что насколько знаю, 500-ошибка не очень приветствуется.

Comment: `Потому что насколько знаю, 500-ошибка не очень приветствуется.` 
Это кто вам такое сказал? Никогда больше не говорите такого другим людям)) эта два разных типа ошибок, каждый с которых имеет свой полноценный скоуп юзабилити.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка выпадате по той причине, что эти поля в вашем объекте `(@RequestBody User newUser)` есть `required`. 
Вы можете сделать их `optional` в самом классе `User` или сделать проверку на `null` и если вместо какого-то `value` пришел `null` тогда возвращать свою ошибку `return HttpStatuc.BAD_REQUEST` (к примеру, это зависит, какой у вас объект на `return` стоит.

Кроме этого:

1) В этом контексте `500 Internal Server Error` правильная, но не обработанная.

2) `5xx` это `Server Errors`, а `4xx` это `Client Errors`. В данном случае эта ошибка сервера и она правильная и ее не нужно менять на `4xx`. 
Читайте, что такое `REST` и как правильно его писать.

3) Если хотите, чтобы именно в этой ситуации не было `500` тогда в объекте `User` поле `username` допишите в аннотацию аттрибут `@Column(nullable=true)`.

4) Во избежания таких ошибок в будущем, не используйте напрямую `Entity` как `RequestBody` в контроллере. Потому, что объект выходит из под вашего контроля еще до того, как он попадает в сам метод. Для этого создавайте Proxy классы, которые в `Spring Framework` называются `DTO`(Data transfer object), а после этого допишите конвертер в котором уже будет происходить конвертация этого объекта в `Entity` и вся остальная валидация.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [bean validation](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=380)

Модель:

```
public class User {
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    ...
}
```

Контроллер:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> registration(@Valid @RequestBody User newUser, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Все равно приходит 500

Comment: Анализируйте stack trace, смотрите где именно возникает ошибка сервера и почему.

Comment: Конечно приходит 500. Пишет же черным по белому `@NotNull`, а приходит null.

Comment: @DimaKhodan если bean не проходит валидацию, Spring возвращает bad request. Шанс получить ошибку 500 в данном случае отсутствует.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вы правы, но не учли нюанс спрингового `exception handler`, которые любую не обработанную ошибку врапает в 500ю, что и происходит в данной ситуации.